# If a radiobutton is checked,then use the hidden password characters

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I was wondering if it was possible to do something like:

If "RadioButton1" is checked, then have it display the text in "Textbox2.text" with the Password characters.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`UseSystemPasswordChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.usesystempasswordchar.aspx) property:

```
Textbox2.UseSystemPasswordChar = (RadioButton1.Checked);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (RadioButton1.Checked)
{
     textBox2.PasswordChar = '*';
} else {
     textBox2.PasswordChar = '*';
}
```

You can put this code on RadioButton CheckedChanged event...